# Where in this code would I add custom sizes for the application?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have created a script within Google Scripts Editor so that when a user clicks on a menu on the toolbar in Google Sheets it brings up an application box where users click to print.

However, i'm not sure how I could **add custom sizes for that application box** that appears without messing up the code.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Click to print')
      .addItem('Print from Google Cloud', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Click the button below to print using the Google Cloud Print service.');
}
```

and the **index.html** code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/cpgadget.js">
</script>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
    gadget.setPrintButton(
        cloudprint.Gadget.createDefaultPrintButton("button"));
            var liabilityWaiver = waiver.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "Test Page", "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3NraNAa2RhWSldiNklPVGI5OU0");
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="button"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below are image explanations of what the script does:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the last image, that is where the problem is, the application box is too small to fit all of the information on it, therefore cutting it out.

***-EDIT-***

*I managed to work out how to create the application box bigger, with help from a user going by Matt. However, even with the box bigger, the window size where the Google Cloud Print service is located is still small, no matter how big I make the outside application box. (See Image below for reference.)*

[image]

*Could anyone assist with making the inside box the full size of the outside box? Or just simply make it bigger?*

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface-title

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput('<p>A change of speed, a change of style...</p>')
     .setWidth(250)
     .setHeight(300);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not very versed in Google Apps Script at the moment, so could you let me know where to fit this into my code?

Comment: - because when I try and fit this in, it completely gets rid of my print button and seems to substitute it with the "A change of speed, a change of style..." line of text. Even when I get rid of that line of code.

Comment: Seemed to have worked it outside myself, by putting it before the  HTMLOutputFromFile variable - Check out the edit at the bottom of the actual OP and see if you could help with that? I appreciate the help.

Comment: @KFarley I wonder if you can add a style to the HTML - #button { width: <width you set minus a few pixels for the border>; }